# How to install a specific version of drush?

Tags: drush

How can I install the a specific version of Drush, for example 5.9.0?

Comment: How is this too broad? "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format." There's a single, recommended way to install, given in a concise answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recommended way to install Drush is via composer.

`composer global require drush/drush:5.9.0`

See the Drush [README](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush#installupdate---composer) for instructions on installing composer.

Answer (score 1):

A specific version of Drush can be installed using PEAR:

```
 sudo apt-get install php-pear

 pear channel-discover pear.drush.org
```

And then:

```
sudo pear install drush/drush-5.9.0
```

Comment: Pear is no longer a supported installation method; best to move on to composer, as you won't necessarily be able to continue to use pear to get future versions of Drush.

Comment: @greg_1_anderson Is it really "no longer supported"? Drush 7.x is the dev branch, Drush 6.x is stable. Drush 6.x GitHub branch README.md(https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/6.x/README.md) still has pear install instructions.

Comment: It looks like msonnabaum is still supporting PEAR for the 6.x branch; however, you may need to wait a bit for releases. See https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/655. Drush 7 has never been packaged for PEAR, and probably never will be, so it would be best to move on to composer at some point.