# What is the easiest way to install clean Drupal from scratch using drush?

Tags: drush

What is the easiest/quickest way to install clean Drupal from scratch on empty folder for testing purposes by using drush (without resorting to shell scripts or aliases).

Comment: I feel like a competition could break out here...Drupal up and running in one line anyone? Bonus points for as few `&&` and `;` as possible

Comment: _Quickest_ is rather subjective: If you don't have Drush installed, using it is going not to be the quickest way. In my case, the quickest way would be writing a shell command and give it a short name.

Comment: @kernob If you add "without resorting to shell scripts or aliases" I can't see any reason not to open this back up

Comment: Related: [Provide a one command to install and run Drupal command](https://www.drupal.org/node/2911319).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
drush qd
```

Downloads Drupal, runs site install, launches a lightweight webserver, opens a browser and logs you in as 'admin'.

I might have answered `drush quick-drupal`, but Clive said there might be a contest.  :)

Comment: I think you should also provide a version that installs [drush](https://www.drupal.org/node/1791676) for those who don't have it, not everyone sees drush as a prerequisite like you and me =) - This page could become a very valuable resource.

Comment: @Darvanen: All questions tagged with [tag:drush] are required drush to be present. How to install drush, it's another question, so either you can read the instructions at [GitHub](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) (using `composer` it's fairly quick), or check [How to install a specific version of Drush?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118164/install-a-specific-version-of-drush)

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that (about tags meaning prerequisites).  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You may try the following few-line example:

```
$ drush -y dl && cd drupal-7* # Download Drupal and enter folder.
$ drush -y si --db-url="sqlite://db.sqlite" --account-pass=admin # Install.
$ drush rs # Run HTTP server.
```

Your site should be accessible under `http://127.0.0.1:8888`.

Related: [Provide a one command to install and run Drupal command](https://www.drupal.org/node/2911319).

Answer (score 1):

Starting on a new, clean VM is another option with Vagrant. Once you have Vagrant / VirtualBox running, installing Drupal 6 to 7 is a breeze https://www.drupal.org/node/2008792

Update : With the fast development of Drupal 8, VDD mentioned above still works fine with Drupal 7 but does not support Drupal 8 anymore. 
If you want to quickstart a Drupal 8 website, prefer [DrupalVM](http://www.drupalvm.com/), it is much more maintained, is easy to configure (via Yaml settings) and covers the latest version of Drush (8) + have support for Apache or Nginx, Varnish, Solr, XDebug, XHProf, ...