# Drush 9 command equivalent to core-quick-drupal (qd)?

Tags: drush, installation

In Drush 8, there is a `core-quick-drupal` ([`qd`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/134768/1908)) command, however, it's missing in Drush 9.

Is there any equivalent command in Drush 9 which allows to download, install and serve Drupal with minimal configuration and dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drush qd` is not currently available in Drush 9. It would be easy enough to make a short shell script to call `composer create-project` followed by `drush site-install` and `drush uli`.

This command will probably reappear in a later release, sometime after 9.0.0 stable. A pull request that implemented `qd` would also be welcome.